# Handling a Large Kafka topic

Tags: apache-kafka, partition

I have a very very large(count of messages) Kafka topic, it might have more than 20M message per second, but, message size is small, it's just some plain text, each less than 1KB, I can use several partitions per topic, and also I can use several servers to work on one topic and they will consume one of the partitions in the topic... 
what if I need +100 servers for a huge topic?

Is it logical to create +100 partitions or more on a single topic?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that many partitions. You don't need servers, though, just processes / threads

Answer (score 2):

You should define "large" when mentioning Kafka topics:

- Large means huge data in terms of volume size.
- Message size is large that it takes time sending a message from queue to client for processing?
- Intensive write to that topic? In that case, do you need to process read as fast as possible? (i.e: can we delay process data for about 1 hour)
- ...

In either case, you should better think on the consumer side for a better design topic and partition. For instances:

- Processing time for each message is slow, and it better process fast between messages: In that case, you should create many partitions. It is like a load balancer and server relationship, you create many workers for doing your job.
- If only some message types, the time processing is slow, you should consider moving to a new topic. There is a nice article: [Should you put several event types in the same Kafka topic](http://martin.kleppmann.com/2018/01/18/event-types-in-kafka-topic.html) explains this decision.
- Is the order of messages important? for example, message A happens before message B, message A should be processed first. In this case, you should make all messages of the same type going to the same partition (only the same partition can maintain message order), or move to a separate topic (with a single partition).
- ...

After you have a proper design for topic and partition, it is come to question: how many partitions should you have for each topic. Increasing total partitions will increase your throughput, but at the same time, it will affect availability or latency. There are some good topics [here](https://www.confluent.io/blog/how-choose-number-topics-partitions-kafka-cluster) and [here](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/kafka-optimization-how-many-partitions-needed-maria-hatfield-phd/) that explain carefully how will total partitions per topic affect the performance. In my opinion, you should benchmark directly on your system to choose the correct value. It depends on many factors of your system: processing power of server machine, network capacity, memory ...

And the last part, you don't need 100 servers for 100 partitions. Kafka will try to balance all partitions between servers, but it is just optional. For example, if you have 1 topic with 7 partitions running on 3 servers, there will be 2 servers store 2 partitions each and 1 server stores 3 partitions. (so 2*2 + 3*1 = 7). In the newer version of Kafka, the mapping between partition and server information will be stored on the zookeeper.

Answer (score 0):

you will get better help, if you are more specific and provide some numbers like what is your expected load per second and what is each message size etc,

in general Kafka is pretty powerful and behind the seances it writes the data to buffer and periodically flush the data to disk. and as per the benchmark done by confluent a while back, Kafka cluster with 6 node supports around 0.8 million messages per second below is bench marking pic [image]

Answer (score 0):

Our friends were right, I refer you to this book

**Kafka, The Definitive Guide**
by **Neha Narkhede, Gwen Shapira & Todd Palino**

You can find the answer on page *47*

> **How to Choose the Number of Partitions**
>
> There are several factors to consider when choosing the number of
>   partitions:
>
> - What is the throughput you expect to achieve for the topic?
>
>   For example, do you expect to write 100 KB per second or 1 GB per
>     second?
> - What is the maximum throughput you expect to achieve when consuming from a single partition?   You will always have, at most, one consumer
>     reading from a partition, so if you know that your slower consumer
>     writes the data to a database and this database never handles more
>     than 50 MB per second from each thread writing to it, then you know
>     you are limited to 60MB throughput when consuming from a partition.
> - You can go through the same exercise to estimate the maxi mum throughput per producer for a single partition, but since producers
>     are typically much faster than consumers, it is usu‐ ally safe to skip
>     this.
> - If you are sending messages to partitions based on keys, adding partitions later can be very challenging, so calculate throughput
>     based on your expected future usage, not the cur‐ rent usage.
> - Consider the number of partitions you will place on each broker and available diskspace and network bandwidth per broker.
> - Avoid overestimating, as each partition uses memory and other resources on the broker and will increase the time for leader
>     elections. With all this in mind, it’s clear that you want many
>     partitions but not too many. If you have some estimate regarding the
>     target throughput of the topic and the expected throughput of the con‐
>     sumers, you can divide the target throughput by the expected con‐
>     sumer throughput and derive the number of partitions this way. So if I
>     want to be able to write and read 1 GB/sec from a topic, and I know
>     each consumer can only process 50 MB/s, then I know I need at least 20
>     partitions. This way, I can have 20 consumers reading from the topic
>     and achieve 1 GB/sec. If you don’t have this detailed information, our
>     experience suggests that limiting the size of the partition on the
>     disk to less than 6 GB per day of retention often gives satisfactory
>     results.